# Loader Blinking When Keyup Executes

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a loader right next to input field at which trigerred when the input field retrieves keyup event. This works like I want but the loader seems to be blinking everytime the keyup event's fired.

I mean it's blinkin' cause it's turn back to its original condition overtime. I know it is event handler works. However, how to deal with the blinkin' loader to make it rotate as it should even if it retrieves keyup event?

HTML:-

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <input type="text" name="nip" class="form-control" id="nip" placeholder="NIP" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 check">
      <span id="pesan"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:-

```
$("#nip, #nis").keyup(function(){
    $("#pesan").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-periksa animated infinite flash">Memeriksa Data</span>')
.fadeIn(600);
});
```

Comment: You're re-setting the HTML everytime someone stops typing. The browser has to re-draw everything again and again and again and again and again. Every single time you press a key.

Comment: So how to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the blinking, I would set `#pesan` HTML only if it's empty.

```
$("#nip, #nis").keyup(function(){

  if($("#pesan").html() == ""){
    $("#pesan").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-periksa animated infinite flash">Memeriksa Data</span>')
      .fadeIn(600);
  }

});
```

And if the other code you have to remove the spinner (on ajax complete, probably) does not completely remove the HTML, but sets another content... Add an `or` condition:

```
$("#nip, #nis").keyup(function(){

  if($("#pesan").html() == "" || $("#pesan").html() == "Other content"){
    $("#pesan").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-periksa animated infinite flash">Memeriksa Data</span>')
      .fadeIn(600);
  }

});
```

Comment: wow... your first 'if' clause works like a charm. Now, I can't apply it to my ajax. How to apply the if clause inside my ajax? anyway, this is my ajax:
https://pastebin.com/GCnz242K

Comment: I suppose you wish to call the ajax on `keyup` too... Place it outside the `if`. I don't know if that will work correctly if user types fast... It may need to be "debounced".

Comment: Yea, you're right. What I aim for is checking the data if it exists in db. You can edit the aforementioned pastebin. I'm just a bit confusing right now :v

Comment: Check this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/mMNPmR?editors=1111). I use a `setTimeout` to "filter" a couple keyup events. So the Ajax is called only if there was 600ms of "no typing" since last keyup.

Comment: your first if clause works only when the page is first loaded and the input field is filled. but second time i'm playing with the input field it turns back blinking anyway. your setTimeout doesn't work, mate

Comment: Thank you so much anyway for helpin me this far mate

Comment: I dont get your *"second time i'm playing with the input field"*. The setTimeout is there to filter keyups on typing a nip like "7874". It will call Ajax ONE time if user type "normally", instead of calling it 4 times. That is what I meant with "debouncing".

Comment: Here's the thing... When i refresh the page and I fill the input field, your if clause works in a way that the loader's not blinking. but afterwards, what I meant to play with the input field is when I fill and remove the value turnaround, the loader turns back blinking when it comes to my ajax

Comment: That is your "logic" that is in cause here. You have to write the event handlers to make them do what you want. So if I understand you, you should add a condition to check if the `input` is NOT empty... --- By the way, I just saw your pastebin... You should not set a event handler inside another one like this. Place the `keyup` handler outside the `change` handler.

Comment: okay mate. thank you so much. I know it's extremely stupid to have another event handler inside an event handler :v. Okay bro thank you so much. Could you create a simple pseudo-code to make this works?

Comment: mmm... It is supposed to be the one who "desings" the interaction to implement to write pseudo-code. I won't desing anything for you. StackOverflow is about help on coding issues. Not on desing suggestions. The reason is that I'm not sure how you want *«to make this works»*. --- What I can tell you is the `change` event occurs when user leaves the input after a modification inside it... Like a click out or a tab out. So the `keyup` handler is not defined until the first `change`... That seems wrong... But may be correct. That is up to you to code your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Bootstrap.
One way you can do this is by having your HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 check">
    <span id="pesan" class="hidden">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-periksa animated infinite flash">Memeriksa Data</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then, on your code, you can just do:

```
var $pesan = $("#pesan");
$("#nip, #nis").keyup(function(){
    if($pesan.not(":visible"))
    {
        if($pesan.hasClass("hidden"))
        {
            $pesan.css("display", "none").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        $pesan.fadeIn(600);
    }
});
```

The `removeClass` is there so you only need to use the class `hidden`, provided by Bootstrap.
The code can be simplified if you use `style="display:none"`.

---

All together now:

```js
var $pesan = $("#pesan");
$("#nip, #nis").keyup(function(){
    if($pesan.not(":visible"))
    {
        if($pesan.hasClass("hidden"))
        {
            $pesan.css("display", "none").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        $pesan.fadeIn(600);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" name="nip" class="form-control" id="nip" placeholder="NIP" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 check">
    <span id="pesan" class="hidden">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-periksa animated infinite flash">Memeriksa Data</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mate. It solved. you can check my ajax in which not yet solved https://pastebin.com/GCnz242K

Comment: @mending3 Not trying to be mean or anything, but, your Ajax code is outside the scope of your question. I suggest you to separate it into a different question, showing the problem you have and what you expect it to do, and what you've tried.

Comment: Considering it's still the same context, I think it's fine to solve it out at once mate. Thank you anyway

Comment: @mending3 Then add it into the question.